# C++ pure virtual method defined at run-time

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

Not sure if the name is very telling but here goes.

I am interfacing to an API that requires a base class to be inherited and a lot of pure virtual methods to be defined.

For good programming practice, I want these methods to be defined in different (sub) classes.

Currently, I use a facade/wrapper (kind of both) class, that inherits the base class, instantiates the sub-classes, and calls the necessary methods of these instantiated classes:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void reqImplementation( void ) = 0;
};

class APIImplementation
{
  private:

    Base * ptr_;

  public:
    APIImplementation( Base * ptr ) :
      ptr_( ptr )
    {
      ptr_->reqImplementation();
    }
};

class MyImplementation
{
  private:
    APIImplementation * api_;
  public:
    void reqImplementation( void )
    {
      printf("Hello World!\n");
    }

    MyImplementation( APIImplementation * api ) : api_( api ) {}
};

class MyFacade : public Base
{
  private:
    MyImplementation * my_impl_;
    APIImplementation * api_;

    void reqImplementation( void )
    {
      my_impl_->reqImplementation();
    }

  public:
    MyFacade( void )
    {
      api_ = new APIImplementation( this );
      my_impl_ = new MyImplementation( api_ );
    }
};

int main( void )
{
  MyFacade my_facade;
  return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to implement the pure virtual functions in the sub-classes instantiated within this facade/wrapper? Or, alternately, what would be good practice for something like this? I want something similar to this (I know it clearly doesn't work at the moment):

```
#include <cstdio>

class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void reqImplementation( void ) = 0;
};

class APIImplementation
{
  private:

    Base * ptr_;

  public:
    APIImplementation( Base * ptr ) :
      ptr_( ptr )
    {
      ptr_->reqImplementation();
    }
};

class MyImplementation : public Base
{
  private:
    APIImplementation * api_;
  public:
    void reqImplementation( void )
    {
      printf("Hello World!\n");
    }

    MyImplementation( APIImplementation * api ) : api_( api ) {}
};

class MyFacade : public Base
{
  private:
    MyImplementation * my_impl_;
    APIImplementation * api_;

  public:
    MyFacade( void )
    {
      api_ = new APIImplementation( this );
      my_impl_ = new MyImplementation( api_ );
    }
};

int main( void )
{
  MyFacade my_facade;
  return 0;
}
```

Note the API source is open, so I can change these pure virtual methods to anything else, however the code is quite exhaustive, so I'd rather small changes than significant ones.

Comment: What are the public methods of MyFacad? It seems to be playing the role of Adaptor, Resource Manager...though they way you init it in main it would seem that it also exposes your API?

Comment: (The general concern being the way you've got this setup there is no clear ownership. If APIImplementation actually takes a ptr argument I guess that you can work around it, but this seems like a good way to encorage memory leaks and segfaults)

Comment: Expose the API... If my understanding of exposing an API is correct i.e. in this case, to enable the API to begin calling methods of (interacting with) MyFacade.

APIImplementation is the class I would prefer to remain constant, unfortunately.

Comment: You have several options but all of them have some tradeoffs so you have to say a bit more what do you dislike about your solution. BTW the second code *does* compile if you define reqImplementation on MyFacade: http://ideone.com/WRyHhc

Comment: It seems like it could be done better without an enormous facade that simply redirects method calls to sub-classes.

I was aware of the recompilation, however the code doesn't execute how I intend (APIImplementation doesn't know to call the MyImplementation method, as opposed to the MyFacade method)

Comment: @OliverCliff I still don't quite understand what you are trying to do. For instance, you said that APIImplementation doesn't know the call to MyImplementation but that would be a matter of using api_ = new APIImplementation( new MyImplementation ); instead of api_ = new APIImplementation( this ); Are you trying to group several Base* calls in just one?

Comment: @OliverCliff Actually, I didn't get what you're asking at all. Could you tell exactly how does that API looks like? For example, when you say "requires a base class to be inherited", there's no clue base class of what is required to inherit something, and it's quite vague where "pure virtual methods" are to be defined.

Comment: @Pedrom I believe the example is somewhat misleading (that is my mistake.) In my program, MyImplementation is simply one of about 20 sub-classes that is implementing one part (say, 5 pure virtual methods of out 100) of the response to the API. I want a MyImplementation method to be called e.g. when ptr_->reqImplementation() is called, but a different sub-class to be called when a different method is called.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph The API specifies that the object pointer that is passed to it upon instantiation (`this` in my code) must be a derived class of `Base` i.e. pass it `Base *`.

Comment: @OliverCliff Passed to what? Could you explain it consistently, after all?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Passed to the `APIImplementation` class (may be a misnomer I realize).

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you need a virtual inheritance. Here's an example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// base class with lots of methods (two, actually)
struct Base {
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;
};

// here's a class with implementation of f
struct ImplementationPart1 : public virtual Base {
    virtual void f() {
        cout << 4;
    }
};

// here's a class with implementation of g
struct ImplementationPart2 : public virtual Base {
    virtual void g() {
        cout << 2;
    }
};

// here's a class with all the implementations
struct Implementation : public ImplementationPart1, public ImplementationPart2 {};

int main() {
    // Implementation inherits from Base, yes
    Base *x = new Implementation();
    // everything works, as expected
    x->f();
    x->g();
}
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/WkBhGF)